# Exception in async task gets intercepted in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, asynchronous

I want to run several tasks, some of which would complete async'ly, and then wait for all of them to complete. As the tasks may throw exceptions, I want to catch and log them. sample code for that:

```
static async Task doit(int x)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}  start", x, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2 + x));  // simulate long-running stuff worth awaiting...
            if (x == 3)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception inside task " + x.ToString());  // Simulate the async task throwing exception
            }
        });

        if (x == 2)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception after task " + x.ToString());  // Simulate post-async task throwing exception
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}  end", x, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}  Exception: {2}", x, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, ex.Message);
    }
}

private static void TestTasks()
{
    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(n => doit(n)).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting");
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine("all end");
}
```

If I run this code from console, it works as expected, with this output:

```
1  1  start
2  1  start
3  1  start
Waiting
1  3  end
2  4  Exception: Exception after task 2
3  5  Exception: Exception inside task 3
all end
```

However, if I debug inside Visual Studio, the debugger stops at the noted exception with `Exception was unhandled by user code`. Then I need to hit `F5 Continue` for the code to complete.

I noticed that if I disable Options => Debugger => `Enable Just My Code`, the debugger doesn't stop. However, I don't want to set this permanently, since some of the frameworks I use handle my exceptions that I *do* want the debugger to stop on.

- Why does the debugger stop even though the exception is inside a try/catch?
- How can I get the debugger not to stop at this exception?

Comment: How about **Debug -> Start without debugging**?

Comment: @Mike: Of course I could do that, but I do want to set breakpoints.

Comment: Not sure it will do it, but try decorating the `doit(int x)` with the `[DebuggerStepThrough]` attribute. The side effect is that breakpoints in the method will also not work. Not sure you can have your cake and eat it too in this situation.

Comment: @Ron: Nope, doesn't change the situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the debugger stop even though the exception is inside a try/catch?

Technically, the code is throwing an exception that is not caught by any of *your* code on the current call stack. It's caught by the (compiler-generated) `async` state machine and placed on the returned task. Later, when the task returned from `Task.Run` is `await`ed, that exception is **re**thrown.

> How can I get the debugger not to stop at this exception?

Right now, your only options are to have the debugger ignore this exception in some way (disable just my code, disable breaking on user-unhandled exceptions of that type, ...).

If you think VS should offer a better user experience here, feel free to open a uservoice suggestion.

Comment: Looks like VS _does_ offer a better experience now: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/exception-helper-rethrown-exceptions/?utm_source=vs_developer_news

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the debugger stop even though the exception is inside a try/catch?

This behavior apparently depends on the version of Visual Studio.

I ran into the same issue in Visual 2013. I tried to build and debug the same code with Visual 2015 Update 1. This time, the debugger correctly handled the exception and did not stop.

You did not mention which version of Visual you were using. If it was one older than 2015, you could try using Visual 2015 or newer and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Still happens in Visual Studio 2017 15.9.12.