# how to debug exceptions when using async methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, visual-studio-2017

In asp.net MVC, when I'm debugging and stepping over code, the debugger will stop at an offending line and show me the exception being thrown without the line being in a try..catch. However, when working with lines that are await..async, the debugger doesn't pause and the exception is just returned back as a response before I have a chance to see it in debugger. Is there a setting in VS2017, where I can pause the debugger and examine this exception when calling async methods?

Comment: Are these async Task or async void methods?

Comment: Can you supply a little code?  Remember when debugging only the error on the UI thread is going to get caught by VS debugger.  When error handling you have to remember what thread the error is being thrown on.

Comment: @JStevens I am able to catch exceptions when putting the offending await line calling an async method within a try block. So I am not sure why the debugger can't figure it out on its own that when a particular thread has thrown an exception, it should show me the exception in debugger and pause there, rather than just pass it along to the response.

Comment: The debugger is running in the UI thread.  Think of it this way. Debugger is you, you have 2 kids T1 and T2. T1 is in the car going to the mall with you. Meanwhile T2 went with friends to the movies. T2 is not in your car. You have no idea what he is really doing. You only know what you told him to do. You are not there to catch his mistakes.

Comment: yep that makes sense. so is there a way to tell the debugger to attach to a particular thread?

Comment: In short no.  The UI thread exist while the application is running.  Other threads will be adhoc.  Created when needed and destroyed when not in use.

Answer (score -1):

Just place a break-point manually in the desired method ahead of time by pressing **F9** there. First line of code in that method is a good logical place. Then launch a debugger and do usual **F10** or **F5** as work your way. At some point (which you don't control) you'll be stopped at desired point.

Comment: I am not asking how to debug. I am asking how to view an exception while debugging.

Comment: You should be able to catch exception from await..async execution just like any other exception, just make sure you're using `await` or `Wait()`, so exception instance will be available for inspection. Alternatively, even if you have `catch()` , i.e. without explicit exception declaration, you can simply add `$exception` in VS's watch window and inspect the same way.

Comment: yes but that's what i would like to avoid is putting in try..catch just to debug

Comment: I guess I'm getting a bit confused. You wanted to view an exception, but you don't like try..catch in your code? Consider coding unit test with try..catch. However, if you're able to step into code that throws exception you can observe it while in debug without catch(). In VS go to Options->Debug->General, turn on "enable the exception assistant". You also didn't specify if you're using `async void` or `async Task` signature, as was asked earlier. It's unclear if you want to catch/handle exception programmaticaly or while in debug session.

Comment: I just want to be able to delve into an exception as i step over the code if the code i'm stepping over happens to throw an exception. This works fine normally, but it doesn't with async..await.

Comment: Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847825/exception-in-async-task-gets-intercepted-in-visual-studio. What's your Options => Debugger => Enable Just My Code value?